# Display currently logged-in user information in react/redux using socket io

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, socket.io

for an app I'm making I'm developing a user database containing email, password (jwt-token), first name and last name. Now to keep track of which users are logged in, I use socket-io with TypeScript. On the server side it seems to be working fine, as any time someone logs in it shows a message in the kernel User {first name} has just connected.

```
//server/index.ts
io.use(socketIoJwtAuth.authenticate({ secret }, async (payload, done) => {
          const user = await User.findOne(payload.id)
          if (user) done(null, user)
          else done(null, false, `Invalid JWT user ID`)
        }))

        io.on('connect', socket => {
          const name = socket.request.user.firstName
          console.log(`User ${name} just connected`)

          socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            console.log(`User ${name} just disconnected`)
          })
        })
```

Now I'm using react redux for the frontend side and I want to display the user's first and last name whenever they login. Basically what I would like to know is how to get the information that is succesfully retrieved in the above server-side code and use it in the frontend with react/redux to display user information whenever that user logs in.

Thanks for any help!